# Object following cursor freezes after camera pan operation begins

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a `GameObject`, let's call it `editor`, that follows the position of the mouse in the world using the below script:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class FollowCursor : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Update()
    {
        Plane objPlane = new Plane(-Camera.main.transform.forward,
            gameObject.transform.position);
        Ray mouseRay = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        if (objPlane.Raycast(mouseRay, out float distance))
        {
            gameObject.transform.position = mouseRay.GetPoint(distance);
        }
    }
}
```

This `editor` object is used in many places, one of which is to control panning of the camera. I control this panning using the script below, which is attached to the main camera:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CameraControls : MonoBehaviour
{
    FollowCursor editor;
    Vector2 camPosOnClick;
    Vector2 mousePosOnClick;

    public Vector2 RelativeToCamera(Vector2 worldPoint)
    {
        return worldPoint - (Vector2)gameObject.transform.position;
    }

    public Vector2 RelativeToWorld(Vector2 camPoint)
    {
        return camPoint + (Vector2)gameObject.transform.position;
    }

    void Start()
    {
        editor = GameObject.FindWithTag("GameController")
            .GetComponent<FollowCursor>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1))
        {
            camPosOnClick = gameObject.transform.position;
            mousePosOnClick =
                RelativeToCamera(editor.gameObject.transform.position);
        }
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(1))
        {
            Vector2 change = mousePosOnClick
                - RelativeToCamera(editor.gameObject.transform.position);
            gameObject.transform.position = camPosOnClick + change;
        }
    }
}
```

The intended behavior of this code is upon right clicking, the position of the editor (tracking the mouse position) and the camera are saved. Each frame, the distance between the current editor position and the saved position (which equates to the drag distance) is added to the camera's saved position.

I can see no reason this code shouldn't work, but nothing happens when I right click. The action of right clicking causes the editor object to stop tracking its position; the raycast it uses fails every frame after right-clicking. I cannot figure out what right-clicking is doing that affects this raycast, nor how to fix it. Is there a flaw in this code that I have missed?

Comment: Just in general why not for the `FollowCursor` just use `Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition + Vector3.forward * someFixedDistance);` ?

Comment: In the code you posted you are only storing some values in fields bit don't change anything on the `FollowCursor` or the camera so I don't see why it should behave like you described... Are you sure there is nothing else influencing these two?

Comment: @derHugo I am changing the camera’s position. Perhaps that is the issue?